# Google Test and Visual Studio 2010 RC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, googletest

Has anyone tried to build **[gtest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) 1.4.0** under VS 2010 RC?
I get about 400 errors when I try to build it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it fails on its own `tr1::tuple` implementation - adding `GTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE=0` to my preprocessor defines fixed the problem for me ([bugtracker issue](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/issues/detail?id=217&can=1&q=2010)).

Comment: Thanks, this solves the same rather nasty issue when building Google Protocol Buffers (protobuf).